# calling .exe from cmd and .exe should launch another cmd by staying in same window

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I have one .exe say abc.exe, the goal of this exe is to invoke cmd. I am calling this exe from cmd. After running exe from cmd, I am getting a seperate new window of cmd. Instead I want to open new cmd in the same window. Is it possible?

This is the code I am using to invoke cmd through exe

```
  using (Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"))
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
```

In command line I am giving path of exe i.e path/abc.exe

Comment: It would help if you include the commands you use to run the exe from cmd, and the code which the exe uses to invoke cmd.

Comment: I have included..@Adrian

Comment: Your executable is being built as a GUI application.  If you build it as a console application you will get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score -1):

Each executable file contains it's own GUI. and when you start a new process it is executed thoroughly and it can not open as a part of your application.

I still am not sure what is your scenario and what your purpose is. But, I think you need something like IFrame in Asp.net.